# MacBook Pro 15" 2018 External Display Issue

Tags: hdmi, macbook-pro, external-display, usb-c

I have a 29" LG Ultra Wide monitor, which was working perfectly with my 13" MBP 2015 (connected directly via HDMI - HDMI).

I have bought a 2018 MBP 15" that only has USB-C ports and I'm having issues with the monitor now. On the first day I connected it with a USB-C to USB-C cable and it worked. Next morning the monitor could not be detected. I switched to a USB-C to HDMI cable and the monitor worked, but only for few days. After that I tried to switch back to USB-C to USB-C cable and it worked again for a day. The USB-C cable right now acts as if nothing was connected. The USB-C to HDMI cable now switches the graphic card on my mac from integrated to discrete, but the monitor is not detected (plus the whole system starts lagging).

I have no way how to test the cables (I have no other computer with USB-C input), but the monitor is OK on the desktop (HDMI-HDMI connection). Also from what I described above I think something is wrong in OSX.